# Find first hidden row in every table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, hidden

I just want to implement the feature "Add row" for several tables at the same time.

I have these tables with all their rows hidden. When I press the button "Add row" I want to show a new row in every table. I guess it is possible to do it with `:hidden`and `:first-of-type`selectors but I'm not able to do it...

Do you know what am I doing wrong?

The example is here --> http://jsfiddle.net/WxzfQ/399/

Comment: table.find('tr:hidden:first-child') -> http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/WxzfQ/400/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
$('input').click(function(){
    $("table tbody").find('tr:hidden:first').show();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NHT32/)

when you say `table tbody tr:hidden:first-of-type`, it matches the first row of the tbody if it is hidden, if the first row is not hidden then it does not match the selector

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').click(function(){    
$("table").each(function(){  $(this).find("tbody tr:hidden:eq(0)").show(); } );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention tbody in your jquery selector, but you don't actually have a tbody element in your table. Also, your fiddle uses jQuery 1.4.2, but first-of-type was added in 1.9.

http://jsfiddle.net/wAGJq/1/

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
    ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
```